# Android Access Checkbox in AdapterView

Tags: android, layout, checkbox, adapter

I have this second right aligned nav drawer which is filled by an adapter with checkboxes. 
When I change those checkboxes, the name of the the CB gets stored (or removed) in an StringSet and committed to my apps sharedPrefs. - *this is working.*

Now I want to retrieve those Strings when the app starts and automatically check those boxes, So the user doesn't have to!

But I have absolutely no clue how to access the CheckBox...

[image: What it looks like]

This ist **my adapter** so far:

```
package de.timhartmann.ledcontroller;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by Tim on 02.03.2015.
 */
public class NavDrawerZonesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList mData;
    public Set<String> selectedStrings = new HashSet<String>();

    public NavDrawerZonesAdapter(Map<String, String> map) {
        mData = new ArrayList();
        mData.addAll(map.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO implement you own logic with ID
        return 0;
    }

    public void refreshList(Map<String, String> map){

        mData.clear();
        mData.addAll(map.entrySet());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView zone;
        TextView IP;
        CheckBox ZoneCheckBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Context context = parent.getContext();

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_zones_adapter, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

           viewHolder.ZoneCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                   if (isChecked) {
                       selectedStrings.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
                       editor.putStringSet("zones", selectedStrings).commit();
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Checkbox: " + buttonView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }else{
                       selectedStrings.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
                       editor.putStringSet("zones", selectedStrings).commit();
                   }

               }

           });

        }

        else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        Map.Entry zones = (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
        viewHolder.ZoneCheckBox.setText((CharSequence) zones.getKey());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And the **Adapters Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When app start then After complete draw of view you firstly check that if

```
checkBox.isChecked()
```

if it gives to true then make search otherwise don't.

Currently you only did this on

```
viewHolder.ZoneCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener
```

So whenever checkbox state change it will happen othewrwise not.

**Edited**

As pe ryour comment I have new logic

As you are storing the text in shared prefrence same you can store the position of that checkbok/view too.

//In adapter class
Now at the starting check if sharedprefrence contains this position key and get that position from shared prefrence then compare that position with your adapter position and set checkbox true at that position

```
 if(sharedprefrence.contains("positionkey") && sharedprefrence.get("positionkey","").equals(String.valueOf(position))){

    //setcheckbox true at this poition 
    }
```

Comment: yes, but how can I access the box? if I try to access the cb to check if it  is named like one of the Strings in my StringSet, like this `if (selectedStrings.contains(viewHolder.ZoneCheckBox.getText().toString())){viewHolder.ZoneCheckBox.setChecked(true);}` it doesn't work